# In SQL, what is the memory-efficient way of "mapping" 1 ID to multiple IDs?

Tags: sql, algorithm, design-patterns, memory-management

I'll describe my scenario so you guys understand what type of design pattern I'm looking for.

I'm making an application where I provide someone with a link that is associated with one or more files. For example, someone needs `somePowerpoint.ppx`, `main.cpp` and `somevid.mp4`, and I have a tool that makes `kj13h1djdsja213j1hhadad9933932` associated with those 3 files so that I can give someone

```
mysite.com/getfiles?fid=kj13h1djdsja213j1hhadad9933932
```

and they'll get a list of those files that they can download individually or all at once.

Since I'm new to SQL, the only way I know of doing that is having my tool use a table like

```
     fid                        |          filename
------------------------------------------------------------------
kj13h1djdsja213j1hhadad9933932            somePowerpoint.ppx
kj13h1djdsja213j1hhadad9933932            main.cpp
kj13h1djdsja213j1hhadad9933932            somevid.mp4
jj133823u22h248884h4h24h01h232            someotherfile.someextension
```

to go along with the above example. It would be nice if I could do some equivalent of

```
     fid                        |          filename(s)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
kj13h1djdsja213j1hhadad9933932      somePowerpoint.ppx, main.cpp, somevid.mp4
jj133823u22h248884h4h24h01h232            someotherfile.someextension
```

but I'm not sure if that's possible or  if I should be using some other design pattern altogether.

Any advice?

Comment: You need store the information as the first format. You can get the result in your second format later.

Comment: Isn't the first format inefficient? There has to be a better way.

Comment: @user4905335 The first format may be a bit less efficient (definitely in terms of disk space, difficult to say in terms of query performance without a benchmark), but it also makes the database much easier to maintain.  With a relational database you'll generally want to start out with a [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) format (like your first format) - only switch to a denormalized format (like your second format) if your benchmarks call for it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string) can help give you a query that would generate your condensed format (you'd still want to store it in SQL with the full list, but you could make a view showing the condensed version using the query in the link)